# How to remove Redirect Chain's from my website - wordpress

Tags: redirect, optimization, httprequest, minimize, chain

Wordpress Newbie here. I am trying to optimize my website and GT metrics is showing me a very low score on minimize redirects. It says

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

https://match.prod.bidr.io/cookie-sync/pm&gdpr=0&gdpr_consent=
https://cm.g.doubleclick.net/pixel?google_nid=beeswaxio&google_sc=&google_hm=QUFtNGYwNjl6T2NBQUFfa1pwY09UUQ&bee_sync_partners=sas%2Csyn%2Cpp%2Cpm&bee_sync_current_partner=adx&bee_sync_initiator=pm&bee_sync_hop_count=1
https://match.prod.bidr.io/cookie-sync/adx?bee_sync_partners=sas%2Csyn%2Cpp%2Cpm&bee_sync_current_partner=adx&bee_sync_initiator=pm&bee_sync_hop_count=1
https://rtb-csync.smartadserver.com/redir?partnerid=127&partneruserid=AAm4f069zOcAAA_kZpcOTQ&redirurl=https%3A%2F%2Fmatch.prod.bidr.io%2Fcookie-sync%3Fbee_sync_partners%3Dsyn%252Cpp%252Cpm%26bee_sync_current_partner%3Dsas%26bee_sync_initiator%3Dadx%26bee_sync_hop_count%3D2%26userid%3DSMART_USER_ID
https://match.prod.bidr.io/cookie-sync?bee_sync_partners=syn%2Cpp%2Cpm&bee_sync_current_partner=sas&bee_sync_initiator=adx&bee_sync_hop_count=2&userid=5474368427267615867
https://sync.technoratimedia.com/services?srv=cs&pid=73&uid=AAm4f069zOcAAA_kZpcOTQ&cb=https%3A%2F%2Fmatch.prod.bidr.io%2Fcookie-sync%3Fuserid%3D5474368427267615867%26bee_sync_partners%3Dpp%252Cpm%26bee_sync_current_partner%3Dsyn%26bee_sync_initiator%3Dadx%26bee_sync_hop_count%3D3
https://match.prod.bidr.io/cookie-sync?userid=5474368427267615867&bee_sync_partners=pp,pm&bee_sync_current_partner=syn&bee_sync_initiator=adx&bee_sync_hop_count=3
https://image2.pubmatic.com/AdServer/Pug?vcode=bz0yJnR5cGU9MSZjb2RlPTMyOTcmdGw9MTI5NjAw&piggybackCookie=AAm4f069zOcAAA_kZpcOTQ

.... and there are atleast 50 more like the above.
For the life of me I am unable to trace the source of these links and how and where they are being generated. I have searched the Database, have clicked on the view page source of my webiste but i am unable to find any of these links.
I have tried de-activating the plugins but they still show.
Kindly let me know how I can kill these requests.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a content security policy to solve this issue and improve overall optimization of my webiste.
I used the Content Security Policy Generator plugin available in Google chrome web store to generate the content security policy.
I then Installed the HTTP Security Options Plugin onto my wordpress site and applied the Content security policy generated by the generator in the CSP Options.
I tweaked around with the content security policy by replacing the subdomain with *. to have coverage of sub domains. I also added a slash at the end of the domain which seemed to help eg: *.domain.com/. I now have no redirect URL's on GT Metrix and have a score of 100%